# How to properly use ActiveYaml with Rails 3.0.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I ran across ActiveHash/ActiveYaml while learning Rails and wanted to use it to load lookup data. After following the installation directions, I got the ActiveHash::Base stuff working. I'm trying to load data from a YML file that looks like this:

```
   AK:
   name: Alaska
   abbreviation: AK

   AL:
   name: Alabama
   abbreviation: AL
```

I have a class in my *models* folder called *usstates.rb* that looks like this:

```
   class USState < ActiveYaml::Base
     set_root_path "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/constants/"
     set_filename "USStates"

     fields :name, :abbreviation
   end
```

I've tried to place my YML file in both the */config/constants/* and *models* folder. Each time I try to do something in Rails Console like *USState.first*, I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant USState
```

How do I get this to load the YML file and show the items? This also fails if I comment out the sets in the class.